# DLNA versus APIPA

Tags: mobile, ip, wifi, android-wifi, dhcp

I recently notice that in my mobile phone wifi settings, there is a `DLNA auto-ip` option that's already checked. As its description : "**Check to use DLNA when no DHCP server is available**",

I found that's *something* the same as APIPA mechanism:  "**With APIPA (Automatic Private IP Addressing), DHCP clients can automatically self-configure an IP address and subnet mask when a DHCP server isn't available.**"

What's DLNA meant here and what are the differences between DLNA and APIPA?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the DLNA specification, we have to support auto-IP when
there is no DHCP server.
"dhcpcd" is used by android and it supports auto-IP, but there are 2
designs
inside framework make auto-IP not available.
1. wireless manager timeout is the same as default DHCP discover
timeout.(30s)
2. dhcpcd will set failed property when get auto-IP

We have tried following methods to modify dhcpcd.
1. Using property system
a. When DLNA is on, set property to note its status.
b. dhcpcd reads status property. When status is on, set default DHCP
discover timeout to 10s.
c. Script reads status property. When status is on, set result
property to "ok" for IPv4LL case.
Property system is not for general applications. Thus we can not
accomplish step a.

2-1. Write status file
a. When DLNA is on, write status file in the application folder.
b. dhcpcd read status file. When status is on, set default DHCP
discover timeout to 10s.
c. script read status file. When status is on, set result property
to "ok" for IPv4LL case.
The step c is a script, if condition and file access always cause
error. So we make a change again.

2-2. Write status file and create a new reason for dhcpcd
a. When DLNA is on, write status file in the application folder.
b. dhcpcd read status file. When status is on, set default DHCP
discover timeout to 10s.
c. dhcpcd read status file. When status is on, set reason to new
created one. The case in script is alwayse set result property to
"ok".